# Multi progress bars Iteration not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm doing a progress bar using jQuery. I have passed a percentage value using a variable. But only the first value executed to all bars.

Actually, I want to create a `variable` dynamically that takes a changed value for the current bar.

I just started learning jQuery. If anything is wrong here feel free to tell and please suggest any other way to do it.

Any help will be appreciated Thanks.

```js
moveProgressBar();
   
function moveProgressBar() 
{
    $('.progress-wrap').each(function() {
        var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
        console.log(getPercent);        
        var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
        console.log(getProgressWrapWidth);
        var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
       
        $('.progress-bar').animate({
            left: progressTotal
        }, 2500);
    });
};
```

```css
.progress {
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3379b7;
}
.progress-wrap .progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 0 #e6e6e6;
}
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: -65px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
 font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="11">
    <div class="progress-bar progress">
        <div class="bar">11%</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="6">
    <div class="progress-bar progress">
        <div class="bar">6%</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="3">
    <div class="progress-bar progress">
        <div class="bar">3%</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="14">
   <div class="progress-bar progress">
       <div class="bar">14%</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="66">
   <div class="progress-bar progress">
       <div class="bar">66%</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/3d047g78/

Comment: @Hackerman i mean only first value executed to all bars `ex: 11%` takes for all bars 11 only.

Comment: Fixed https://jsfiddle.net/3d047g78/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using each function you need to use `this`:

```js
  moveProgressBar();
   

    function moveProgressBar() {
        
         $('.progress-wrap').each(function() {
        var getPercent = ($(this).data('progress-percent') / 100);
        console.log(getPercent);        
        var getProgressWrapWidth = $(this).width();
        console.log(getProgressWrapWidth);
        var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
       
        $(this).find('.progress-bar').animate({
            left: progressTotal
        }, 2500);
    });
};
```

```css
.progress {
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.progress-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3379b7;
}
.progress-wrap .progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 0 #e6e6e6;
}
.bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: -65px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
 font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="11">
      <div class="progress-bar progress">
       <div class="bar">11%</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="6">
      <div class="progress-bar progress">
       <div class="bar">6%</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="3">
      <div class="progress-bar progress">
       <div class="bar">3%</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="14">
      <div class="progress-bar progress">
       <div class="bar">14%</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="66">
      <div class="progress-bar progress">
       <div class="bar">66%</div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Funny, just the exact same thing that I did :)